# Serilog: How do I remove unnecessary information Net core 6

Tags: c#, json, serilog

I'm using ASP net core 6 and I don't have the startup class. Of course, I programmed the whole thing in Visual studio code 2022

The problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDEKQ.png)

I don't want the location to be shown in the console.
You can see Below AppSettings.Json

```
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "Serilog": {
"Using": [],
"MinimunLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Overrite": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\Demos\\Logs\\Log.txt"
    }
```

Otherwise, all the other information I need is shown and it works, only I don't want the location to be shown

Comment: Have you looked at [Serilog filtering expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions)? It can filter out the logs even for specific sink

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.
I'll see if I can find what I'm looking for and no, I haven't seen it. I'm still a beginner and know little about serilog.

Comment: Two good writeups: https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/  https://blog.datalust.co/using-serilog-in-net-6/

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Overrite` with `Override`